# again the utf8 issue with rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8

Again i stand here and pull my hair..

So im makeing app in Latvian language. So it needs utf8 encoding.
I tried to put various configurations in initializers, like:

- Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
- Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8

Tried various comments, like:

- # encoding: utf-8

In my view layout file i have:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

I have my db connection set to utf8, and have no problem with that, actually.

The problem i have is, that i cant just use UTF8 chars in my views. Every time i get this error:

```
incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

Im sure, that my files are encoded in utf8. I dont have a clue what i could do, to make rails app to read utf8 correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i found a fix, that was good for me, but made a new post, cos this needs more info, i think.. I dont think this is the correct way of doing it, but well.. it fixed all my problems, so maybe this will help for someone else..

[is this fix for Rails utf8 issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603763/is-this-fix-for-rails-utf8-issue)

Comment: You should add that post as an answer here, rather.